# Do not want rounded corners in the AppBar when the Sliver App Bar is collapsed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I'm trying to implement a layout, where the Sliver App Bar has rounded bottom corners when expanded, but when it is collapsed I do not want those rounded corners.

Actual Behaviour:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFmGA.png)

[image]

[image]

Expected Behaviour:

[image]

[image]

Here's my SliverAppBar code:

```
`SliverAppBar(
          systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Color(0xFFE0E64B),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE0E64B),
          expandedHeight: 300.0,
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          collapsedHeight: 60.0,
          onStretchTrigger: () async {
            setState(() {});
          },
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Pokedex',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '#025',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
            background: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFE0E64B),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(50.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'pokemon_container$index',
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 120.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        child: Image.network(
                          imageUrl,
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
```

Here is your code. Put it inside sliverAppBar

Comment: thank you for quick response. The issue with this approach is that when I collapse the app bar, it still have the rounded corners. I want the appbar to have rounded corners only when it is expanded

Comment: man, I am not sure that we can do it only with SliverAppBar.  Maybe it can be done with functionality but this issue beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

### NestedScrollView / SliverAppBar solution

This is definitely achievable. `SliverAppBar` does support what we need, it has support for rounded borders, the shadow effect and changing sizes. For handling the border requirement we can use a `RoundedRectangleBorder`.

Although for getting a smooth transition for the border change, we need to update the values frequently, when changing the size of the `SliverAppBar`.

#### Example code

Do note that the package `flutter_riverpod` (version 1.0.3) is used for state management in this example.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class RoundedSliverExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundedSliverExampleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            ExpandingAppBar(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                // Flexible is important for the children widgets added here.
                Flexible(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow, width: 50, height: 50,))
              ],
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text("Hello!")
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

/// An SliverAppBar widget with alternating rounded border depending on the
/// expandedHeight.
///
/// Provides easy support for adding children widgets in the
/// expanded area as if it was a Column, although children widgets should be
/// wrapped in a Flexible widget.
class ExpandingAppBar extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ExpandingAppBar({
    Key? key,
    this.children = const <Widget>[],
    this.mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    RoundedHeaderState state = ref.watch(roundedHeaderProvider);

    return SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: state.highestHeight,
      pinned: true,
      primary: true,
      forceElevated: true,
      title: const Text('Pokèdex'),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(state.radius)),
      ),
      flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          // We update the state here.
          ref.read(roundedHeaderProvider.notifier).updateHeight(constraints.maxHeight);

          return Opacity(
            opacity: state.scrollFraction,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: state.smallestHeight),
              child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment, children: children),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

@immutable
class RoundedHeaderState {
  final double highestHeight = 256;
  final double smallestHeight = kToolbarHeight + 24;
  final double currentHeight;
  final double contentOpacity = 1;

  const RoundedHeaderState({this.currentHeight = 256});

  double get scrollFraction => min(max((currentHeight - smallestHeight) / (highestHeight - smallestHeight), 0), 1);
  double get radius => 64 * scrollFraction;
}

class RoundedHeaderNotifier extends StateNotifier<RoundedHeaderState> {
  RoundedHeaderNotifier(): super(const RoundedHeaderState());

  updateHeight(double currentHeight) {
    final newState = RoundedHeaderState(currentHeight: currentHeight);

    // Check that the new state is not equal to the next (prevents rebuild loop)
    if(state.currentHeight != newState.currentHeight) {

      // Setting state triggers an rebuild, the PostFrameCallback let Flutter
      // postpone the upcoming rebuild at a later time.
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        state = newState;
      });
    }
  }
}

final roundedHeaderProvider = StateNotifierProvider<RoundedHeaderNotifier, RoundedHeaderState>((ref) {
  return RoundedHeaderNotifier();
});

// Pay attention to the ProviderScope wrapping the MaterialApp. Riverpod requires this.
void main() => runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(home: RoundedSliverExampleScreen())
    )
);
```

#### Result - Gif of the SliverAppBar's transition.

[image: Result gif showing the transition in the App bar when it goes from expanded to collapsed and back, on Windows.]